# jQuery Tablesorter Pager not working in Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, tablesorter

I'm trying to use the tablesorterPager addon to paginate a table. I've followed [this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/sorting-tables-tablesorter/) precisely, but when I load the page, I see the whole table and I get a console error saying that tablesorterPager is undefined.

Here is my JS code in my HTML page:

```
  $(function(){
    $("#myTable").tablesorter();
  });

  $('#my-table')
   .tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    widget: ['zebra']
  })
   .tablesorterPager({
    container: $('#pager'),
    size: 2
  });
```

I have identical copies of the JS and CSS files from the tutorial and they are loading just fine. When the page loads, I can sort the table, but none of the pagination features work. I'm still very new to JS and jQuery so I don't know how to debug the problem further.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to to put it all inside the page ready function?

```
$(function(){
  $("#myTable").tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    widget: ['zebra']
  })
  .tablesorterPager({
    container: $('#pager'),
    size: 2
  });
});
```

Comment: That had no effect. Same problem is still happening.

Comment: Are there any other errors in the console? If not can you add your html to question.

Comment: No more errors. I figured out the problem. The jquery.tablesorter.pager.js file wasn't being compiled by Rails for some reason, even though I added it to my application.js file. I added a call to it in the layout file and it seems to be working now.

Comment: I had to add `//= require jquery-tablesorter/addons/pager/jquery.tablesorter.pager` to my application.js file.